# When is the destructor of an object that is being moved to called in C++?

Tags: c++, callback, destructor

I have some class `A`, which I can either construct using nothing, or an `std::function`. On destruction that given function should be called (in case there is one). My problem is that the object gets destroyed right after it is created and returned by my `getSomeA()` function which calls the `std::function` before it is supposed to be called. The function passed to the constructor should only be called once. Some example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

static void testFunction(const std::string& msg)
{
    std::cout << "TestFunction: " << msg << "\n";
}

class A {
public:
    A(void) = default;

    A(const std::function<void()>& onDestroy) :
        onDestroy(onDestroy)
    {  }

    ~A(void)
    {
        if (onDestroy) onDestroy();
        else std::cout << "in dtor but no onDestroy was set\n";
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> onDestroy;
};

A getSomeA(void)
{
    return A(std::bind(testFunction, "the A that was created inside getSomeA"));
}

int main(void)
{
    A b1;
    std::cout << "After creating b1\n";
    b1 = getSomeA();
    std::cout << "After reassigning b1\n";

    std::cout << "Here the program works with b1...\n";
}
```

The program outputs

```
After creating b1
TestFunction: the A that was created inside getSomeA
After reassigning b1
Here the program works with b1...
TestFunction: the A that was created inside getSomeA
```

So the function is called before it is supposed to be called (at the end of int main()).

After adding a move constructor and assignment operator everything works as expected:

```
A(A&& other) :
        onDestroy(std::exchange(other.onDestroy, nullptr))
    {  }

    A& operator=(A&& other)
    {
        onDestroy = std::exchange(other.onDestroy, nullptr);
        return *this;
    }
```

And the program outputs

```
After creating b1
in dtor but no onDestroy was set
After reassigning b1
Here the program works with b1...
TestFunction: the A that was created inside getSomeA
```

The actual question: Where is the object destroyed for the first time so that testFunction is called? In `getSomeA()` or in the main function before the assignment but after the object was created in `getSomeA()`?

All the edits: I tried to bring down my question for one hour but since I have no idea about move/copy semantics in C++ that was pretty hard for me.

Comment: Can you simplify this question a bit please? Make it easy for us to help. There's a lot to read at the moment.

Comment: Sure, I'll try.

Comment: `A& operator=(A other)` is a copy-assignment operator, not a move-assignment operator.

Comment: Move semantics doesn't change an object's lifetime, only management of the object's inner resources. Regardless of its content, if an object is in dynamic memory then it is destroyed when `delete` is called on it, if an object is in automatic memory then it is destroyed when it goes out of scope. If an object is a temporary, it goes out of scope at the end of the statement that creates it. So, if you don't implement the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) correctly, then you will have bad things happen when copied-from/moved-from objects are destroyed.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings actually, that operator can act as both a copy-assignment and a move-assignment operator, if `A` implements both a copy constructor and a move constructor

Comment: @RemyLebeau http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#1 http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#3 ‍♂️ It may be able to act like a move-assignment operator (and it can't, really; all you can control is whether the argument is moved-into at the callsite), but it isn't one.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh. So I have to use the rule of 3 basically as soon as I have something to manage - which in my case are callbacks. The destructor which caused my new "A" object to be deleted was it going out of scope in the `getSomeA()`, right? Can I take it as guaranteed that the move semantics take care of temporary objects? Thank you for tha fast comment.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings `A& operator=(A other)` may not be *defined* as a move operator, but it does act as a viable move operator, if a move constructor is implemented. `A a; a = other;` (copy) and `A a; a = std::move(other);` (move) both work as expected.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not sure what else to tell you. The standard clearly defines what is a copy assignment operator, and what is a move assignment operator. What the OP has shown meets the definition of the former, not the latter. ‍♂️ There's really no scope for disagreement here.

Comment: @kesslerbebe yes, exactly.  `getSomeA()` returns a temporary, which you can copy/move from into `b1` if you have proper `operator=` implementation(s) in place.

Comment: Of course you can make it so that it is invoked without a copy: that's always been the case. Do we now call every `A& operator=(const A& other)` a "move constructor"? No...

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings whatever. Defined or not, it is not uncommon practice to implement both copy-assignment and move-assignment using a single `operator=`, and it works just fine, and is well-defined behavior using copy/move constructors. That is all I'm going to say.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I never disputed any of that (and I would do it that way myself). I am merely correcting the terminology in the question. Not sure why you took issue with that...

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings terminology refers to  special function signatures *generated by compiler* If user defines overriding ones with equivalent signatures and behaviour, it doesn't change functions's purpose.  I.e. user-defined copy constructor may take non-const parameter, it only limits or extends class's copyability (requires mutable argument, can mutate argument - transfer semantics)

Comment: `A& operator=(A other)`  would be ambiguous with `A& operator=(A&& other)`  in context of move operation attempted, so it _is_ equivalent of move operator.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Irrelevant. This is not a move assignment operator. That is just a plain, simple, provable fact. That you can `std::move` into the argument for a copy assignment operator is entirely besides the point.

Comment: @AsteroidWithWings then what it is if it overloads compiler-defined move assignment and is not a copy assignment by definition (because argument is not T&, const T& or volatile T&)? This appears to be a defect of standard overlooking this possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version the object gets destroyed for the first time as part of returning the object constructed in `getSomeA`. Its `return` statement effectively constructs a temporary object, which then gets assigned to `main`'s `b1`. If you ignore the process of returning from a function, the sequence of events is:

```
A <temporary object>(std::bind( ... )

b1=<temporary object>

<temporary object gets destroyed>
```

At this point the bound function gets called, as a result of the temporary object gets destroyed. The temporary object is a fully tricked out object, with all the rights and privileged granted thereof. Including a destructor.

But wait, there's more! `b1` is a perfect bit-by-bit copy of the original object, with the bound function, before it got destroyed. So when `b1` gets destroyed, the function gets called again.

This is the indirect consequence of the [Rule Of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). When an object owns a resource, and must maintain an exclusive ownership of the resource you will need to provide a copy and/or move constructor ***and*** and assignment operator to spell out exactly what should happen in that situation.

P.S. these rules change slightly with C++17's guaranteed copy elision, but the underlying concept is still the same.